# Передача массива на rest и его сохранение в БД

Tags: java, массивы, rest, spring-boot

Делаю rest сервис. Задача передать Json массив и сохранить его в базе.

На данный момент так:

**MessageController**

```
//Add one message
    @RequestMapping(
            value = "/api/message",
            method = RequestMethod.POST,
            consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<?> addMessage(@RequestBody Message newMessage) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(messageRepository.save(newMessage), HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    //Add array of messages
    @RequestMapping(
            value = "api/messages",
            method = RequestMethod.POST,
            consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<?> addMessages(@RequestBody List<Message> newMessages) {

        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(messageRepository.save(newMessages), HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```

Сохраняется и один элемент и Json массив.
Далее хочу ввести слой сервиса.

```
public interface MessageService {
    Message save(Message message);
    Message saveArray(List<Message> messages);



@Service
public class MessageServiceImp implements MessageService{

    private MessageRepository messageRepository;
    @Override
    public Message save(Message message) {
        return messageRepository.save(message);
    }

    @Override
    public Message saveArray(List<Message> messages) {
        return messageRepository.save(messages); //а тут я уже запутался
    }
```

Почему напрямую в контроллере метод save перебирает массив, а тут получается вроде нет? Как это должно выглядеть?

Добавлено:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "message")
public class Message {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private long id;
    @Column(name = "MESSAGE")
    private String message;
    @Column(name = "AUTHOR")
    private String author;
    @Column(name = "CREATED")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date created = new Date();

    public Message() {
    }

    public Message(Long id, String message, String author, Date created) {
        this.id = id;
        this.message = message;
        this.author = author;
        this.created = created;
    }
+ getters / setters
```

Comment: Какую структуру имеет `Message`? Что происходит в месте `//а тут я уже запутался`? Исключение? Если да, то какое?

Comment: @Maksim Message добавил. Там я передаю массив, но мой IDE ругается "no instance of type varibles S exist so that List<S> conforms to Message"

Comment: Проверьте, что вы тот `Message` испортируете в класс сервиса

Comment: Импортирую и другие методы findAll, findOne, update, delete работают с Message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильный ответ.

**MessageServiceImp.java**

```
@Override
public List<Message> saveArray(List<Message> messages) {
    return messageRepository.save(messages);
}
```

**MessageController.java**

```
//Add array of messages
@RequestMapping(
        value = "api/messages",
        method = RequestMethod.POST,
        consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<?> addMessages(@RequestBody List<Message> messages) {
    return new ResponseEntity<Object>(messageService.saveArray(messages), HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```